# Oneplus 5 GCM Push Notification Issue with optimize

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

While integrating the GCM push notifications I am facing a particular issue on Oneplus 5 device. The phone is unable to receive notification while having the battery optimization feature active for particular app.

Is there any way to receive notification while having this feature turned ON.

Any help would be appreciated.